# How to detect the back panel tap in android as fast like fox game does?

Tags: java, android

Any one know **how to detect the back panel tap in android** as this game [Fast like fox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waybefore.fastlikeafox) does

I want to do something when user tapps on back of his/her mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Better unpack that game and try out yourself in the AndroidManifest.xml if it uses a permission or hardware capability, as not many devices have that functionality.
Thanks.